# RTK useLazyQuery always making calls to the API even when called with same params on multiple components

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to make a request use the cached data from another component when doing a lazy query. The parent component (not direct parent, so I don't want to drill down a large data set through props) makes a lazy query through RTK like so:

```
const [getDocuments, { data: contractDocuments, isLoading, isFetching }] = useLazyGetContractDocumentsQuery();


// inside a fetch function
  getDocuments({
    prop1,
    prop2,
    prop3,
  });
```

Then the child component does the same

```
getDocuments({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3,
}).unwrap().then(documents=>{
  console.log(documents);         
});
```

I have verified that the props are the same, the data returned is the same, but in both cases every time it is called in either component it hits the API endpoint to get the data. It never gets it from cache.

The documentation seems to say that the lazy queries are different than regular useQuery by the fact that you choose when to call. See the [Feature Comparison](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#feature-comparison) of the different hooks. But I have not been able to use the cache with them. Am I missinterpreting the documentation, missed some exception to the caching rule or there is the chance that in another place I am disabling caching somehow?

Btw, the query looks like this:

```
    getContractDocuments: builder.query<
      ContractDocument[],
      {
        prop1: string;
        prop2: string | null;
        prop3: string;
      }
    >({
      query: body => ({
        url: '/GetDocuments',
        body,
        method: 'POST',
      }),
      transformResponse: (response: ContractDocument[]) => {
        return response.map(d => ({
          ...d,
          showIconViewFileInNewWindows: extensions.has(`${d.type}`),
        }));
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the lazy query trigger always make a request call, however you can provide a second argument as true to use cache when available

```js
getDocuments({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3,
}, true)
```

See [docs (UseLazyQueryTrigger)](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I missed that part on the docs! I was breaking my head trying to make it sue cache haha.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful information!

Comment: when does this cache gets invalidated ? is it like default 60 seconds after the component gets un-mounted ?